# programmatically how to read CCD and CCR xml Content using C# in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

> it is a CCD xml which used in my asp.net project.but I have problem that how it could be read its Xml content using C# code.so please healp me.i am put this CCD xml.

http://www.md-it.com/sites/default/files/CCD.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below URL to read CCD and CCR XML content:

http://medbi.blogspot.in/2008/02/creating-c-bindings-for-ccr-and-ccd.html

Comment: hai deepak, i see this link butthis class not declare ContinuityOfCareRecord in code